# What does "Find focus on your customers." mean?

Tags: redundancy

I am editing a piece of marketing with the headline "Find focus on your customers." Is it redundant to use "find" with "focus"? I'm not sure I understand what "find focus" means. Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: It's redundant. And no - you're just *thinking*!

Comment: 'Find focus' and 'focus on ...' are fine. Redundancy is where more words than are necessary to get the meaning across are used in a grammatical way. This is ungrammatical.

Comment: It means you need a better headline.

Comment: *Find focus* is based on analogy with optical work. Your first view of a small animal in your microscope may be blurred but you adjust the device until the animal is clearly seen - you have then found the correct focus. Nevertheless, you should heed the  three prior comments. A marketing person is not a microscopist.

Answer (score 1):

Finding is the goal of searching but as Anton has pointed out *Finding Focus* while useful in some context is not so much here. This suffers from the current trend of piling on more words or new words to attract attention and improve meaning. It is a distraction to the literate and hardly makes a ripple in the sea of copy out there. Another offender is the excessive use of *Leverage*: "We will leverage our insights in amalgam to thrust forward this quarter."

The goal should not be to *seek out* the focus but to *Make* the customer the focus. A somewhat different perspective.